# use Guzzle to access secretsmanager query API

Tags: php, guzzle, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to access to Secrets Manager AWS Service using Guzzle 3 (I know it's an old version, but it's the one used in the project)

I successfully have a response when I tried this API on POSTMAN, but when I try to implement the code using guzzle I keep getting Bad Request 400, Can someone help me to figure out what I am doing wrong :

[image: postman response]

```
 try {
          $amzdate = (new DateTime( 'UTC' ))->format( 'Ymd\THis\Z' );
    $amzdate2 = (new DateTime( 'UTC' ))->format( 'Ymd' );
    $secretKey = "MyAWSSecretKey";
    $access_key = "MyAWSAccessKey";
    $region = REGIONID;
    $service = 'secretsmanager';
    $alg='sha256';
    $algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256';
    $signed_headers = 'content-type;host;x-amz-date';
    $canonical_headers = "content-type:"."application/x-amz-json-1.1"."\n"."host:https://secretsmanager.region.amazonaws.com \n"."x-amz-date:".$amzdate."\n";

    $canonical_request = "POST\n /GetSecretValue \n \n".$canonical_headers."\n".$signed_headers."\n";
    
    $credential_scope = (new DateTime( 'UTC' ))->format( 'Ymd' ) . '/' . $region . '/' . $service . '/' . 'aws4_request';
    $string_to_sign  = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n".(new DateTime( 'UTC' ))->format( 'Ymd\THis\Z' ) ."\n".$credential_scope."\n".hash('sha256', $canonical_request)."";
    $kSecret = 'AWS4' . $secretKey;
    $kDate = hash_hmac( $alg, $amzdate2, $kSecret, true );
    $kRegion = hash_hmac( $alg, $region, $kDate, true );
    $kService = hash_hmac( $alg, $service, $kRegion, true );
    $kSigning = hash_hmac( $alg, 'aws4_request', $kService, true );
          $signature = hash_hmac( 'sha256', $string_to_sign, $kSigning );

        $client = new Client();
        $url    = 'https://secretsmanager.REGIONID.amazonaws.com';
        $data = json_encode(array('SecretId' =>'hereSecretID'));

     
        $request = $client->post(
            $url.'/GetSecretValue',
            array(
                'Content-Type' => 'application/x-amz-json-1.1',
                'X-Amz-Target' => 'secretsmanager.GetSecretValue',
                'X-Amz-Date'    => (new DateTime( 'UTC'))->format('Ymd\THis\Z'),
                'Authorization' => 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=ACCESSKEYID/20210526/REGIONID/secretsmanager/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-target, Signature='.$signature
            ),
            $data
        );
      
     
        $response = json_decode($client->send($request)->getBody(true));
        var_dump($response );
    }
    catch(Guzzle\Http\Exception\ClientErrorResponseException $e){
        echo '<pre>',var_dump($e->getResponse()->getBody()),'</pre>';
    }
```

When I try HTTP -cURL, i'am having  : InvalidSignatureException","message":"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."}

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => 'https://secretsmanager.REGIONID.amazonaws.com/GetSecretValue',
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
"SecretId": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-2:940351502967:secret:apiTest-Z4BA9G"
}',
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
'Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1',
'X-Amz-Target: secretsmanager.GetSecretValue',
'X-Amz-Date: '.$amzdate,
'Authorization: '.$authorization_header.', Signature='.$signature
),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Comment: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php

Comment: I wanted to work with AWS SDK PHP but none of de version is compatible with my version Guzzle 3.9 and symfony

Comment: normally bad request comes with error associated to body format have you used debug option

Comment: according to the documentation, the debug is to be added to the 4th parameters when calling post function, I did that but i am not getting any thing different than before, Am I missing smtg ?  https://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/http-client/client.html#debug